# Java - Collision Detection of Two Lines

Tags: java, collision-detection, collision, graphics2d

I have a game where enemies are made of lines with a large g2d.setStroke(); How would I find collision between this line and another line?
Here is where I draw it:

```
g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
//thickness = 35 --- declared previously
g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As math does not seem to be your favourite topic, so let's keep it simple and
use school math.

```
g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
g2d.drawLine(u1, v1, u2, v2);
```

A point on the the two line pieces would be:

```
(x, y) = (x1, y1) + alpha * (x2 - x1, y2 - y1)  where alpha in (0 .. 1).
(x, y) = (u1, v1) + beta * (u2 - u1, v2 - v1)  where beta in (0 .. 1).
```

Any intersecting point has to be on those two line pieces, hence:

```
x1 + alpha * (x2 - x1) = u1 + beta * (u2 - u1);
y1 + alpha * (y2 - y1) = v1 + beta * (v2 - v1);
```

which is the same as:

```
alpha * (x2 - x1) = (u1 - x1) + beta * (u2 - u1);
alpha * (y2 - y1) = (v1 - y1) + beta * (v2 - v1);
```

If there is a solution for alpha and beta within { 0, ..., 1 }, you have got it.

If any cofactor - like `(x2 - x1)` - is 0, you have a simple solution.
Otherwise you can divide/multiply by a cofactor.

Or you could invest a bit of time learning linear algebra basics, matrices and determinants and such. With that knowledge one can also determine whether a 3D surface is turned toward you, or not: the normal vector.